# How to know where I'm from in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, url, pagination, location

I have a question.

Is It possible to know which page I'm from ?

Example. If I go `/blog/` from `home` I'll display a div "From home". Else nothing to display.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use `<?php $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>` ? You will have to extract the page name value from the string, but it should be pretty straight forward, just converting it to an array ([str_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) with '/') and get the correct index for your permalink structure.

Comment: This is the easiest way. Note that some browsers may turn the referer off, it can be freely manipulated by the client (so don't do any security checks with it), and it gets dropped when switching protocols (http:// to https://). It will still work in the vast majority of cases. Everything else would require adding a `from` parameter to every URL which is very, very cumbersome